# Camel proxy Dynamic url Parameter setting

Tags: java, http, proxy, apache-camel

I have a route:

From route is a REST Call.

```
 from("http://com.containerhost:8080/").
    .setHeader("param3",param3)
    .to(anotherURL?queryparam1="queryparam1ofRESTCALL"&queryparam2="queryParam2ofRESTCall"&queryparam3=${header.param3}")
```

But camel is not recognizing this param 3 even though its set in header. In my case param 3 is a key. which has to be added only to a TO uri and it should not be exposed to FROM Uri Rest call.So please tell me how to dynamically add more than one parametes in this scenario.When i went through the forum,they told me to look into recepient list.But couldnt get much info from  Camel http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html  I dont know how to use Recepient list. If you could give me some inputs it will of a great help. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recipient-list with simple is the dynamic-to. Just do:

```
.recipientList(simple("anotherURL?queryparam1=queryparam1ofRESTCALL
                       &queryparam2=queryParam2ofRESTCall
                       &queryparam3=${header.param3}"));
```

Comment: Why is Camel not designed to use a dynamic `to`? This would be more obvious (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the `recipientList` pattern you could just set the `Exchange.HTTP_QUERY` header:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "...");
```